# AWS API Gateway cache with concurrent requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

What I know:

If I make a request through a cache enabled endpoint API Gateway, get a response and make an identical request later, the cache will return the precomputed response.

What I don't know:

If API Gateway receives N identical requests at the same time, will it forward N requests to my service and cache after getting the first response, or will it forward 1 request and wait for the response to return N responses?

I know it sounds like an edge case, but it will be a common situation in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

If API Gateway receives `N` identical requests at the same time, then it will forward all those `N` requests to your service. Only the once the result is cached by API Gateway, then subsequent requests will be served from the cache.